# Accuracy Function: MAPE correction

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, fable-r

I am trying to forecast the hourly visits to a hospital ED. For some hours the actual value is 0 and that is a real problem when I calculate the MAPE for each model.
I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571215/forecasr-accuracy-mape-and-zero-values) where it is suggested the use of MASE (mean absolute scaled error) that is also a metric given by the function accuracy (forecast package). However, in my case, this is not possible because the MASE gives NaN.

So, I try to change the original code for the MAPE function and use only the functions I need for my project:
First I tried this code for MAPE but it does not work since `.resid` and `.actual` are vectors.

```
root_squared_error <- function(.resid, na.rm = TRUE, ...){sqrt(MSE(.resid, na.rm = na.rm))}
Mean_Abs_error <- function(.resid, na.rm = TRUE, ...){ mean(abs(.resid), na.rm = na.rm)}    
Mean_Abs_percentage_error <- function(.resid, .actual, na.rm = TRUE, ...){
      if(.resid == 0){
        if(.actual == 0){
          mean(abs(0), na.rm = na.rm)  
        } else{
          mean(abs(100), na.rm = na.rm)
        }
      }
      mean(abs(.resid / .actual * 100), na.rm = na.rm)
    }

> accuracy(demand_fc_test,test,  measures = list(RMSE = root_squared_error, MAE = Mean_Abs_error, MAPE = Mean_Abs_percentage_error))
        # A tibble: 6 x 6
          .model    MTS    .type   RMSE     MAE  MAPE
          <chr>     <chr>  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
        1 Benchmark Blue   Test  0.459  0.192     Inf
        2 Benchmark Green  Test  3.07   2.16      Inf
        3 Benchmark Orange Test  0.579  0.280     Inf
        4 Benchmark Red    Test  0.0673 0.00453   100
        5 Benchmark White  Test  0.229  0.0516    Inf
        6 Benchmark Yellow Test  2.38   1.74      Inf
        Warning messages:
        1: In if (.resid == 0) { :
          the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

This error message appears 10 times. After some research, I saw examples where the `ifelse` function solved similar problems. However, this does not totally work because it is calculating each error for each value and does not present the summary table.

```
Mean_Abs_percentage_error <- function(.resid, .actual, na.rm = TRUE, ...){
  ifelse(.resid == 0,
         ifelse(.actual == 0, 0, 100),
         abs(.resid / .actual * 100)
  )}

> accuracy(demand_fc_test,test,
+          measures = list(RMSE = root_squared_error, MAE = Mean_Abs_error, MAPE = Mean_Abs_percentage_error))
# A tibble: 13,248 x 6
   .model    MTS   .type  RMSE   MAE  MAPE
   <chr>     <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Benchmark Blue  Test  0.459 0.192     0
 2 Benchmark Blue  Test  0.459 0.192     0
 3 Benchmark Blue  Test  0.459 0.192     0
 4 Benchmark Blue  Test  0.459 0.192     0
 5 Benchmark Blue  Test  0.459 0.192     0
 6 Benchmark Blue  Test  0.459 0.192     0
 7 Benchmark Blue  Test  0.459 0.192     0
 8 Benchmark Blue  Test  0.459 0.192     0
 9 Benchmark Blue  Test  0.459 0.192     0
10 Benchmark Blue  Test  0.459 0.192     0
# ... with 13,238 more rows
```

I think the problem is in the way I'm using the `ifelse` function. I need to apply that condition to each value of each forecast (in the case I have several models) and it should return the mean value of each model. I'm trying to obtain the same output as if I was applying the accuracy function without any changes, this is, I need a tsiblle with n rows and 6 columns where n is the number of models.

Any suggestions on how to solve my problem? 
Thank you in advance.

Example of my data :

```
library(fpp3)
library(fasster)
> dados
# A tsibble: 140,400 x 7 [1h] <UTC>
# Key:       MTS [6]
   Date                  Weekday  MTS     Demand   Temperature  DaysToHoliday DaysAfterHoliday
   <dttm>                <int>   <chr>    <int>       <dbl>         <int>            <int>
 1 2017-05-01 00:00:00    1       Blue     0          11.4            0                0
 2 2017-05-01 01:00:00    1       Blue     0          11.2            0                0
 3 2017-05-01 02:00:00    1       Blue     1          11.2            0                0
 4 2017-05-01 03:00:00    1       Blue     0          10.9            0                0
 5 2017-05-01 04:00:00    1       Blue     1          10.9            0                0
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on a quick search online this is a known shortcoming of MAPE in regards to time series that have zero values in them. The suggestion is to use sMAPE. Here is the wikipedia page I looked and there were a couple of other blog posts when I searched: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error

Disclaimer: Although this should be as a comment as it is not the exact solution, I cannot post a comment due to my current ranking being under 50. I hope this helps.

Comment: I need the MAPE value but if it doesn't work the sMAPE is an equivalent alternative?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, I recommend if you need further explanation post your question in stack exchange. I am also learning about MAPE and sMAPE and based on what I read it is a good replacement for this kind of situations but you have be careful about which formula is being used to calculate the sMAPE.